# Fading Images by swipe or tap between two images

Tags: ios, swift, ipad

I want to create a fade between two images by swiping or taping on the image.

For example:
Two or more images are on top of the another and with swiping to left/right or clicking on the image it would change (not automatically – the picture need a interaction).

Comment: problem is not clear enough please explain more with some screenShots

Comment: is for the iOS system (iPad)
It just have to change images by swiping or taping. like in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=---q4Yt5FMU

Comment: SO is not a free code writing service. Did you try anything?

Comment: i'm learning, but don't know how and where to start. to insert an image or used it as a button is no problem, but how to fade something?

Answer (score 0):

You should place 2 imageviews ontop each other, one as hidden and one as visible. Then place some empty UIButton on top of them to interact on press. The animation part should look something like that more or less:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: { 
        firstImageView.hidden = true
        secondImageView.hidden = false
        }, completion: nil)
```